# NullInjectorError: No provider for Globals

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Im trying to create a global variables file using Angular 6. The variables in this file can be changed by other components. So I saw [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x32any) sample and tried to implement it in my project.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { Globals } from './globals';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SideMenuComponent } from './side-menu/side-menu.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [ Globals ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

side-menu.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { sideMenu } from './side-menu.links.js';
import { Globals } from '../globals.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  isSideMenuOpen: boolean;
  mainLinks: {url: string, target: string}[]}[] = []
  bottomNav: {url: string, target: string}[]}[] = []

  constructor(private globals: Globals) { 
    this.isSideMenuOpen = globals.isSideMenuOpen;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainLinks = sideMenu.mainLinks;
  }

  toggleSideMenu() {
    this.globals.isSideMenuOpen = !this.isSideMenuOpen;
  }

}
```

globals.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  isSideMenuOpen: boolean = true;
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ConfigUi</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body [class.sidemenu-open]="globals.isSideMenuOpen">
  <app-root class="grafana-app"></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The `isSideMenuOpen` boolean is used to add or remove a class from the body. This variable is toggled by a funciton inside the side-menu component using the `toggleSideMenu()` button.

Error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SideMenuComponent -> Globals]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SideMenuComponent -> Globals]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Globals!
```

Why is this not working? How do I make it work?

Comment: Added `Globals ` under `Providers` array of your app module??

Comment: try with putting  ```@Component({
  selector: 'side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css'],
  providers : [Globals]
})```

Comment: if you use Angular 6 version, you should to declare provider inside the @Injectable annotation, like @Injectable(prividedIn: AppModule)

Comment: Try removing the `.js` from `import { Globals } from '../globals.js';`

Comment: @AshishRanjan yes.

Comment: @fatemefazli the point of singleton is to just make a single instance and use it. so can't declare it again.

Comment: @David lol thanks. it was `.ts` not `.js`. Removing it worked.

Comment: but it isn't toggling as its supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the same [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x32any?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

If you add Globals as Provider at your app.module.ts it should work.

And what i did was:

Globals:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  section: string = 'Value';
  
  changeValue(value: string){
     this.section = value;
  }
}
```

And at the component:

```
import { Globals } from '../globals';

export ClassName implement OnInit {
    g: Globals;

    constructor(public globals: Globals){
        this.g = globals;
    }
    
}
```

And then to modify the value, at the html:

```
<div (click)="g.changeValue('StringValue')"> <div>
```